# Handling load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a website which has main domain and sub domain (I have different subdomain for different countries) eg: mysite.com ( is the main domain ), country-a.mysite.com ( for country A ), country-b.mysite.com ( for country B) NOTE: each country has independent users / data and linked with separate databases.

Now I'm managing them in one EC2 instance. Where I have subfolders for each country and point them to subdomain using Route53. And they are working fine.

But now I wanted to them scalable as I'm expecting more traffic. What is the best practice for such scenario ?

Is it possible to get another EC2 instance and clone all the subfolders and introduce a load balancer to handle the traffic between these 2 instances ? I mean, when a user from country A and B will hit the load balancer, the load balancer will handle it properly and redirect the user to the right subfolder in these 2 instances and manage the traffic ?

If yes, how should I configure the Route53 ?

How the load balancer is handling user sessions ? I mean, let say first time a user hit the load balancer direct the user to 1st instance and when the other request comes from the same user hit the 2nd instance. If a session create on the 1st instance and this session data will be available at 2nd instance?

Also I wonder how I can manage the source codes in these instances. I mean, if I wanted to update the code do I have to update in these 2 instance separately? OR is there a easy way where I upload the files to one of the instance and it will clone to other instances ?

BTW, my website built using Laravel framework and Postgres.

Im new to load balancer, pls help me to find the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

> If yes, how should I configure the Route53 ?

There is nothing you should be doing in R53. Its load balancer (LB) that distributes traffic among your instances, not R53. R53 will just direct traffic to the LB, nothing else.

> How the load balancer is handling user sessions ?

It does not handle it. You could enable [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) in your target group (TG) so that LB tries to "maintain state information in order to provide a continuous experience to clients".

However, a better solution is to make your instances **stateless**. This means that all session/state information for your application is kept outside of the instances, e.g. in DynamoDB, ElastiCache or S3. This way you are making your application scalable and eliminate a problem of keeping track of session data stored on individual instances.

> Also I wonder how I can manage the source codes in these instances. I mean, if I wanted to update the code do I have to update in these 2 instance separately?

Yes. Your instances should be identical. Usually [CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) is used to ensure smooth and reproducable updates of number of instances.